# What Websites Have Image Libraries for Bacteria and other Microorganisms

Tags: microbiology, microscopy, fluorescent-microscopy

What Websites Have Image Libraries for Bacteria and other Microorganisms?

With age of cell phone microscopes and hand held spectrometers it would be interesting and valuable to be able to compare in-home/at-work microbiology with data-banks. To be able to test for health or enjoy the visuals of tree of life seem relevant. What websites are out there?

Comment: Sites for microscope blood analysis would be a nice compliment to this.

Answer (score 4):

While I doubt that this might be possible in all cases (and I would be careful about classifications), there are indeed some great ressources, which contain a lot of images. Since there is a vast number of bacteria present on this planet, there is of course a limitation to bacteria available in photos, representing only the most common or important.

These are:

- [Bacteria in Photos](http://www.bacteriainphotos.com/index.html)
- [American Society of Microbiologies Microbelibrary](http://www.microbelibrary.org/home)
- [Microbiology in Photos](http://www.microbiologyinpictures.com/)

Then there is an information page available from the CDC, which informs about parasitic diseases. These are non-bacterial, but probably also interesting. It can be found here:

- [Laboratory Identification of Parasitic Diseases of Public Health
  Concern](http://www.cdc.gov/dpdx/az.html)